# Quick way to add Bump node

Tags: materials, node-editor

This is what i got but how it works can anybody explain me.

[Node wrangler auto texture setup](https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/6mls3h/new_feature_in_node_wrangler_addon_auto_texture/)

This is my image below

[image]

Is there any quick way to add a bump node. With press 1 click it should set the nodes and just can add the images in the position. Like a macro or any addon just press 1 click and it set all bump nodes and i have to just drop the images in that. Im having 75 buildings and i want to add all of them the bump so always i have to select the material add 5-6 nodes so if there is a quick way. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

[image]

or

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Activate the Node Wrangler Addon.

With the sphere unwrap

Click on add material with the selected default material just change the diffuse material to Principled BSDF.

Before u go to next step u must save the image with the name (normal, spec, Ambient, disp.) Note : without name it will not work so just the normal name should be to the images so that addon find out correctly.

With the Principled BSDF Node Selected Press Ctrl+Shift+T

A window target select the file which are saved with the name

Click ok and render

[image]